# scrollview mask not working unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, scrollview, mask

I am experiencing the issue with text colour not changing to what I set in the inspector resulting in always black text.

I have followed the advise to create a material and assign that to the font and this appears to work, but only on a static text field or button text.

I have a text field in a scrollview and after I apply the material the scrollview mask no longer hides the text outside of the scroll area?

If I set the material shader to GUI/TextShader I get the correct colour, but the srollview mask does not work, if I set it to no material the mask works but colour is black?

This happens on every font as soon as I add a material?

I have tried all manner of shader setting without any joy, does anyone know how to resolve this?  It seems totally bonkers to me :-(

Answer (score 0):

SORTED!

I imported TextMesh Pro, used its Font Creation Tool and hey presto :-)

Not sure why the default Unity text component cant handle this?